# SQL query executes long via CLR and uses all CPU, but only on some databases

Tags: sql-server, performance, clr

We have a strange case in SQL Server query behavior.
We have a couple of queries that executes great on 1 database, but on another (with very similar number of records), it runs 'forever'. 
On the one DB, it runs in about 5 secs, and on the other I've killed the process after 25 minutes.

What we know:

- On the database that takes a long time, the query will start using 100% of the CPU and the entire server comes to a halt.
- Looking at the sysprocesses table, there are 9x SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD waittypes for the bad database with a high CPU usage (all in a runnable state)
- This behavior of good vs bad only seems to happen when running the code through the .NET CLR (Visual Studio, LinqPad). When taking the resulting SQL statement and executing it in SSMS, both databases are working fine.  It thus does not seem to be something in the query, but perhaps something in the DB.
- Rebuilding indexes or repairing the DB does not make a difference.

(I'm sure someone might ask for a sample of the query, but it seems to happen on different queries. We would prefer to fix the database rather than going through all the queries and fixing them one-by-one.)

Any advice or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: [Why is my query suddenly slower than it was yesterday?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204565/why-is-my-query-suddenly-slower-than-it-was-yesterday)

Comment: Thanks @Denis. I worked through the post.  Some valuable info there, but no success for me. The post does seem to address SQL Server issues 'directly', but as our query works fine in SQL I think most of the suggestion there does not apply. It's only via the CLR that it misbehaves.

Comment: Have a look at [Why is My Database Application so Slow?](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-performance/database-application-slow/)

Comment: If a query takes too much CPU it usually means that the query performs some scans on big tables/indexes and uses parallelism. That could be a consequence of a wrong query plan plus too low threshold for parallelism (the option affects all your server though, not only some databases).

Comment: We have changed the MAXDOPS and although the CPU does not hit the ceiling it does still take 'forever', That leaves the query execution plan. As 2 DB's with similar record counts are different, I would assume it's something in the index structure or the stats perhaps? Indexes have been rebuild, stats updates, database repaired. Anything else we should try?